# Visual C# Express 2010: Shift+F5 (Stop Debugging) causes Exception

Tags: c#, debugging, exception

Since yesterday I have a problem with Visual C# Express 2010. When I start my app in debug mode, I can't stop id from Visual. It causes Exception:

EventType : clr20r3     P1 : vcsexpress.exe     P2 : 10.0.30319.1
P3 : 4ba1faa8

It starts to shutdown and after a while throws another error:

AppName: vcsexpress.exe      AppVer: 10.0.30319.1     AppStamp:4ba1faa8
ModName: unknown      ModVer: 0.0.0.0      ModStamp:00000000
fDebug: 0       Offset: 0ca09a88

I don't think its problem of my app, because I can push close btn on my app and it closes properly.
Do You have any ideas what could cause the problem and  / or how to fix it?

Comment: Belongs on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com)?

Comment: Did you try to update or reinstall visual studio ?

Comment: Are you sure there is not a thread running in the background in your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a crazy idea, but can you go back to the source of your project from the day before? It may not be your app, but it may in some odd way. Try debugging an earlier version of your app to see what happens.

If it runs ok, try to incrementally make the changes since that version to see whree it breaks.

I saw odd debug behavior years ago that ended up being related to some COM objects I was trying to use. Not suggesting you're using COM objects, but I too assumed it was VS's problem. It wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve the problem for quite some time. Then I left the project for a while and work on sth else. Recently I was reprogramming the project again and there were some problems again. I had no idea so one more time i reinstalled all dotNets and Visual Studio. What a surprise - problems are gone.I guess another mystery I can put into Microsofts X-File.

Thx for Your answers.